# Create a file with form data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a file in server with form data, when a user submit a form all data are saved in the file

Comment: you need a server side language to accept and process

Comment: "server" and "AngularJS" aren't two things that get along pretty well you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you will need to write code on your server and pass your form data using [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Your code may look like below

```
$http.post('/writeFile', JSON.stringify({
   formField1: 'value1',
   formField1: 'value2'
}), config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

And on server (assuming Java)

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(request.getParameter("formField1"));
writer.println(request.getParameter("formField2"));
writer.close();
```

**Note**: This is a sample code and you will obviously need to do changes as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without some server side programming. Make sure that you understand meanings of server side and client side programming. Check [What are the differences between server-side and client-side programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) This will help you to put things in right place.

Comment: Actually this is possible with node js, because it is Server side ...

Comment: @Denis.Sabolotni see edit history of the question. There was no mention of nodejs, question stated if it was possible with AngularJS.

Comment: Yes now I see it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well – kind of. Angular can send data to the server (Angular has a nice promise-based $http service built in ), but it is the servers job to save whatever data you're sending to a .txt-file.

Comment: @RenjithKathirolil have a look at any server-side technology. if you're familiar with JavaScript you'll like Node.js. A lot. IF you heard about PHP, you'll like PHP. A lot.

Comment: @RenjithKathirolil Angular runs in your browser. It's just a *fancy* javascript to do "fancy" stuff. Node JS lets you create a server and run JavaScript code as your primary server-side language.